# string.IsNullOrEmpty using Trim()

Tags: c#, string, trim, isnullorempty

I want to remove the first line:

```
                 !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text)
```

will this cause any issue?

I ran across this in some code:

```
                if ((id % 2 == 0)
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text)
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text.Trim())
                    )
```

I think the first string.IsNullOrEmpty would return false on a string with spaces
and the line with Trim() takes care of that, so the first IsNullOrEmpty is useless

But before I remove the line without the trim I thought I'd run it by the group.

Comment: you mean string.IsNullOrWhitespace

Comment: Is it too hard to test or to look for the official documentation? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx). Short answer: No, a string of spaces is not null or empty.

Comment: You guys are missing the point.  Yes, you can use `IsNullOrEmpty`, but the OP is confused about why the first call is needed to avoid a `NullReferenceException`.  Understanding that is far more important than switching to a different method call because he was told to do so.

Comment: @madth3 I think he is actually asking whether he can omit the first check: `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text)`, not whether `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` checks for white spaces, had to read the question couple of times though.

Comment: @ntziolis You are right, I misunderstand the line to be deleted. I still sustain it's not hard to try it out and check the official docs.

Comment: Thanks Ed S.  Yes, they missed the point - I was trying to understand.

Comment: @BradBoyce However I had to read your question a couple of times, before I understood myself, it's best to clearly state what you want to know, like: I want to remove the first line: `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text)` will this cause any issue?

Comment: madth3 - you're right too.  In retrospect, I guess if I thought about it more I might have figured it out.  But msdn doesn't answer my question either.  I was surprised to see a downvote too.  I really try to make my questions count.

Comment: @ntziolis - thanks for the constructive criticism.  I will try to be more clear in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first IsNullOrEmpty catches null values before they throw a NullReferenceException with Trim().

However, there is a better way:

```
if ((id % 2 == 0) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Text))
```

Answer (score 12):

if cell.Text is null, you'd have an exception without that first check.

Comment: if cell is a TextBox, that property will never be null.

Comment: Which could also be achieved with `cell.Text != null && cell.Text.Trim() != ""` if you still have .NET < .NET 4.0.

Comment: NOTE: cell is  html table cell contents aquired using WebDriver (but that's not the point of the question)

Answer (score 9):

In .NET 4.0:

```
if (id % 2 == 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Text))
{
    ...
}
```

In older versions you should keep the two tests because if you remove the first and `cell.Text` is null, you will get a NRE on the second when you try to invoke `.Trim` on a null instance.

Or you could also do this:

```
if (id % 2 == 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((cell.Text ?? string.Empty).Trim()))
{
    ...
}
```

or even better, you could write an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for the string type that will do this so that you could simply:

```
if (id % 2 == 0 && !cell.Text.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    ...
}
```

which might look like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty((value ?? string.Empty).Trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think an extension method is better in this situation. As a rule of thumb, "don't accept null as a valid extension method parameter". Other programmers might interpreted this as 'Text must have a value because a method could be called'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension method like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates whether the specified string is null or empty.
/// This methods internally uses string.IsNullOrEmpty by trimming the string first which string.IsNullOrEmpty doesn't.
/// .NET's default string.IsNullOrEmpty method return false if a string is just having one blank space.
/// For such cases this custom IsNullOrEmptyWithTrim method is useful.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if the string is null or empty or just having blank spaces;<c>false</c> otherwise.</returns> 
public static bool IsNullOrEmptyWithTrim(this string value)
{
    bool isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return value.Trim().Length == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the test is to ensure that cell.text is not null first... if so, trying to bypass it and get just cell.text.trim() would choke as you can't do a trim on a null string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(call.Text)` and drop the previous two checks?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove just the first IsNullOrEmpty as the cell.Text could be null and thus calling Trim on it would throw and exception. Use [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) if you are using .Net 4.0 or leave both checks.

```
if ((id % 2 == 0) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Text))
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question.  Obviously the OP is confused about how the if statement expression(s) is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If cell.Text is null, the expression string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text.Trim()) will throw an exception since it is trying to run method Trim() on cell.

Much more readble if condition would be: cell.Text!=null && cell.Text.Trim()!=""

Answer (score 0):

We can use null conditional:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell?.Text?.Trim())
```

Note "?" before reading the next property and trim.